# Does 'tense' fit into Lexicology?

Tags: tenses

I am trying to assess errors regarding lexicology in an English-as-a-second-language-learner's spoken English. Does the use of tense fall into the 'Lexicology', Phonology, Syntax or Discourse? I need something in the lexicology area to focus on!

Comment: The first thing to do is to look up the meanings of Lexicology (the study of words and their nature and meaning), Phonology, Syntax, and Discourse. Once you've done that, you'll discover that all are inappropriate for your need. _Tense_ is Grammar.

Comment: Lexicology is word formation and falls under 'lexical morphology'. Tense can come under semantics or syntax or morphology (conjugations and declensions) depending on the usage.

Comment: It also depends on what's meant by "tense". There are a lot of strange ideas about English tenses.

Comment: The above are far from inappropriate for the individual's needs. Tense could actually be studied under each one, depending, of course, on which element of tense she is examining.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this should have been asked on linguisticsSE. Whatever is the answer is probably applicable to any natural language. English tenses are not necessarily subject to special linguistic rules and definitions. May be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

"Lexicology" deals with the meaning and application of words and phrases. "Tense" would fall under the category of "grammar", which is listed under "Syntax" in many Applied Linguistics" programs. So "tense" would fall under Syntax. On the other hand, you might also try "Discourse", for often times, the studies of Pragmatics and Discourse Analysis look at verb tense use as it is applied in "talk-in-interaction".

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Certainly gives me reason to continue studying so I understand the concepts better!

Answer (score -1):

the simple answer is it falls under lexicology which deals with the morphology of words which is what happens when we want to indicate tense.